# JSON in Javascript Unexpected Token B

Tags: javascript, json

I'm parsing the following string in JSON

http://jsfiddle.net/cjds/9mJbq/2/

When I run it chrome throws up the following error `Unexpected Token B`.

Can't figure it out. Because the string is created by PHP json_encode so there shouldn't be a problem with the JSON.

I ran it through JSONLint and there was no error so the JSON is fine.

So what's the error?

Comment: That's not valid JSON at all, looks more like HTML inside an array?

Comment: That makes no sense its created by PHP JSON encode..?

Comment: Then it should be valid JSON, and I'll change my statement to "that data is'nt really appropriate as JSON". It's HTML, why not send it as a HTML string, as there's no benefit in converting a large HTML string to JSON before you send it.

Comment: Its an array of HTML strings. That's why I chose JSON . But PHP seems to have this problem with JSON parsing all strings. Makes no sense.

Comment: it is valid json , try this validator http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I did try JSONlint. Strange error then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter for JSON.parse() should be string.

Thus, `JSON.parse(["hello", "world"])` is wrong.

It should be `JSON.parse("[\"hello\", \"world\"]")`

I updated the jsfiddle. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/9mJbq/3/

Comment: If you could explain why PHP won't just JSON it in the correct way that would be awesome.

Comment: ["hello", "world"] is a valid JSON. However, if you want to pass it to JSON.parse(), it should be stringified. If you make ["hello", "world"] a string, it would be "[\"hello\", \"world\"]". Or you could do '["hello", "world"]'. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

For others arriving at this question, this error occurs if your ajax request is returning 'Bad Request' (error 400) and the json parser is expecting json. For example:

```
const fetchSomething = url =>
    fetch(url).then(data => data.json());
```