# Unexpected token b in position 0

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having Unexpected token b in position 0 from the json that I returned in my php file to my javascript.

```
    $file = array(
            array(
                'src' => 'http://localhost/grapesjs-dev/uploads/'.$_FILES['files']['name'][0],
                'width' => '150',
                'height' => '150',
            )
        );

//var_dump(json_encode($file));
return json_encode($file);die;
```

I have read something that is related to this and could be the solution but I don't know how to change my php code to match the solution that is in this stackoverflow question. [link here guys to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789719/json-in-javascript-unexpected-token-b)

[image to network in debug tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q28nn.png)

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**
I deleted all the var_dumps which gave me the error.
Now I'm getting a new error which is Unexpected end of JSON input.
I changed my json format(the arrays).
And used echo rather than return.

Comment: This looks a bit strange - you're returning a value then calling `die`, which won't ever be reached. Is this code actually inside a function? Where is it actually output to the browser?

Comment: @raold its the name of the file that is uploaded.

Comment: Where is the code that throws the error? Is it in the php, or in javascript? If it's in javascript, how does the json reach that js code? There's not enough here to actually do more than guess what's wrong.

Comment: @iainn die doesnt matter actually. because the return statement was reached hence it returned what I needed before it died.

Comment: where's the code that calls this method? What does it do with the returned json string?

Comment: @ChrisLear the problem is in my javascript. I'm getting unexpected token b in position 0. the problem could be the json that I returned.

Comment: @franzjoseph we still don't know how the javascript gets hold of the json. You can't use a `return` statement in php to send a variable to javascript running in a browser. I'm starting to think that Devang Naghera's answer might be right.

Comment: @Chris Lear have you seen the stackoverflow post I linked?

Comment: It's 100% clear from the network debug what the problem is. The file does not contain json. It contains two var_dump outputs. The first one starts `bool(...`. The first character is `b`, which is what the js is complaining about.

Comment: It's a coincidence that you have an error with a 'b', and the other stackoverflow link has an error with a 'B'. There's nothing special about the b character. The problem is that you aren't actually making json output, just var_dump nonsense

Comment: @ChrisLear I tried removing the var_dumps because it might cause some problem. now it shows a different error. unexpected end of JSON input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `return` to `echo`. That should solve the problem

```
echo json_encode($file);die;
```

Looking at network screen shot it is clear that you are doing `var_dump` somewhere in your `PHP` code which is printing data types rather than actual `json` object, which javascript is unable to read.
Remove the `var_dump` and put `echo json_encode(your_desired_data)` and check it. It should fix the issue.

Comment: I don't really need to print my json. but rather return it.

Comment: Then put the network tab screen shot and show us the actual response your api is returning to the jvascript

Comment: I edited the post. added picture of network in debug tool that my api responded

Comment: Edited the answer :)

Comment: please do look at the stackoverflow post that I linked. like from what I said. I don't need to print the variable. but rather return it. I only used var_dump to check the structure of the variable if it is correct.

Comment: Remove all your var_dumps, and use echo. Then try again

Comment: What is it returning to, JS? Is this an AJAX call? Then it should be echo. `return` is used specifically for PHP functions, not for external callees

Comment: thanks for this. It gave me half of the answet I needed.